# STM32F407VG with LAN8742A through RMII protocol doesn't run

Tags: embedded, stm32, hardware, ethernet, hal

I am looking for help with my own PCB design first running process. I have PCB with STM32F407VG and LAN8742A PHY. After powering on, the orange LED is on constantly, and nothing else. I tried it with the program, and the behavior is the same with an erased chip. I have attached schematic parts, clock configuration, and the board state photo.

I will be grateful for any help and suggestions! Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

[image: board state]

[image: MCU schematic]

[image: PHY schematic]

[image: clock configuration]

I tried to set multiple clock configurations, but nothing came up. Maybe I need to add some power sequence at the start of the MCU. I tried many configurations of reset line and the same effect, just nothing. I don't have any idea what I should do more.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Why are you suspicious of a hardware problem?  Is this custom hardware?  Does "the program" work correctly on another board such as an STMicro NUCLEO board?

Comment: this may be more on-topic on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. There was a missing pull-down resistor on one of the lines.